# css 100% width when horizontall scrollbar

Tags: css, width

I want to have a header with 100% width,
in some cases there is a horizontal scrollbar and that 
causes the div to cover the visible area and not the whole
parent element.

```
.cont {
width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BhRdV/1/

Comment: add them both to the container and set fixed width to that container - http://jsfiddle.net/BhRdV/3/

Comment: I am sorry not been clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain cases, where even if you don't set width to DIV, it will still scale 100%.

Also, please be clear with ur question.

```
<div style="width:1200px;">
<div style="width:100%;">Tadda</div>
<div>Tadda 2</div>
</div>
```